# Passing parameters to url using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I have the Django code as

**views.py**

```
def compare(request):
    import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
    ids = request.GET.getlist('ids', '')
    products = []
    product_matrix = []
    for uuid in ids:
        try:
            product = LoanProduct.objects.get(uuid=uuid)
            products.append(product)
        except LoanProduct.DoesNotExist:
            pass
    if products:
        product_matrix = make_product_matrix(products)


    print product_matrix
    return TemplateResponse(request, "products/compare.html", {'product_matrix': product_matrix})
```

**page1.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
      <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <form action="/products/compare/" method="get">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-9 col-sm-6">
      {% if products %}
      <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th> Check to Compare </th>
                  <th> Product Name</th>
                  <th> Quantum of finance </th>
                  <th> Interest Rate </th>
                  <th> Nature of Security</th>
                  <th> Margin </th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {% for product in products %}
            <tr data-uuid="{{ product.uuid }}" id="uuid">
                  <th><input type="checkbox" name="ids" id="checkbox" value= {{ product.uuid }} /></th>
                  <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ product.get_finance_quantum }}</td>
                  <td>{{ product.get_interest_rate }}</td>
                  <td>{{ product.security }}</td>
                  <td>{{ product.get_margin }}</td>
              </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
      </table>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="compare" class="btn pull-right btn-success"> Compare </button>
</form>
</div>
```

I am having unique uuid for one checkbox. By using that I am getting the items related to that UUID using Django views.By this my url will be `https://localhost:8000/page1?ids=asdf-a972j-aswer&ids=asdf6-asdfewq-asdfwq-dfasfd&ids=asdf0-asdfasdf-asdf`

But I need the URL in this way `https://localhost:8000/page1?ids=sdf-asdf23-as2q3r,sdfqwe-232sasdf-23rwdefr,wqerqr-3qwq2r-23rq23r`

How can I do this using javascript?

Appreciated the answers

Comment: But why are you expecting that URL, rather than the original which is the standard way of using multiple values in HTTP? That way you can get all the values by doing `request.GET.getlist('ids')`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes. I am getting all the values using `request.GET.getlist('ids')` and my part of functionality is working fine for me. But showing the url in the above said format is needed for me. By using the <form> and <submit> actions I will get by default formats of url passing the parameters. I need to override it

Comment: What have you tried? Note that you can't repeat element id in a page, they are unique by definition. Use class instead

Comment: Right now I have tried this code  `$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#compare').click(function() {
  var uuids = '';
  var length = $("input[type='checkbox']").length;
  $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(index){
   uuids = uuids + $(this).val();
   if (index < length-1) {
    uuids = uuids + ',';
   }
  });
  url = '/products/compare/?ids=' + uuids;
  window.location.replace(url);
 });
});`. This splits me to ids=uuid1,uuid2,uuid3,....soon. But how can i get uuid for only checked boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it and made it work.

**working code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#compare').click(function() {
        var uuids = '';
        var length = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
        console.log(length);
        $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(index){
            uuids = uuids + $(this).val();
            if (index < length-1) {
                uuids = uuids + ',';
            }
        });
        url = '/products/compare/?ids=' + uuids;
        window.location.replace(url);
    });
});
```

Finally this gives me the url with uuid's separated with comma's

```
https://localhost:8000/page1?ids=sdf-asdf23-as2q3r,sdfqwe-232sasdf-23rwdefr,wqerqr-3qwq2r-23rq23r
```